# Force CakePHP to return tinyint as int and not bool

Tags: php, cakephp

Trying to make cakephp to return `tinyint(1)` as `int` and not as `bool`. I don't want to change my entire database for small select boxes, just to fit it to CakePHP.

I found the following row at `lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php`

```
if (($col === 'tinyint' && $limit == 1) || $col === 'boolean') {
        return 'boolean';
    }
```

Commenting this line didn't work.

Anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: In MySQL a bool/bit field is really a int(1) field.

Comment: Just cast it as an `int`

Comment: In what debug level are you ? If it is set to 0, the field type may not be updated as it is taken from the cache

Comment: nlcO i'm still building it, and not debugging. just fetch existing db

Comment: Don't! tinyint(1) is always a boolean in Cake. If you need integers (as for enums or other small entities of numbers), use tinyint(2) or tinyint(3) instead! Also, when working with checkboxes, boolean values are just fine. You are creating problems where there are none.

Answer (score 2):

Don't touch the framework. Override the afterFind() method of the model in question and cast your fields to the proper type.

Comment: tried to check the result that afterFind receive.
Cake changes the value of the field before that function runs.
so table.fld = 4 in the db, is shown as 1.

Comment: Well, eventually i found inside the function resultSet the following line `$type = ($column['len'] == 1) ? 'boolean' : 'string';` which did the "magic". thanks all for your help.

Comment: @YK nice, it is here in this file /lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this to stop Cake making your inputs into check boxes?

Just do `array('type'=>'text')` on the `input()`

Comment: i dont have inputs here, i have select box that have 10 values and they're permanent.
trying to display the fields value, but getting 1\0.

Comment: post your actual code; this is unlikely to do with data formats.

Comment: inside the model file  
`function getUserMusic($id) { 
   return $this->find('first', array(
   'fields' => array(
   ),
   'conditions' => array(
    'Music.userid' => $id
   ),
  ));
}`  
inside the controller file  
`$this->set('music', $this->Music->getUserMusic($userid));`  
  
inside the view file  
`debug($music);`

Comment: That all looks fine, just do `pr($music);` in the view and take whatever info you need from the array?

Comment: the problem is this, in the db the field looks like that `array('genre1' => 2, 'genre2' => 3, 'genre3' => 5);` after using find the fields looks like that `array('genre1' => 1, 'genre2' => 1, 'genre3' => 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Never modify the core unless you plan to contribute the changes. If you absolutely have to override the MySQL Datasource, you can do so without modifying the core by copying the file

from

```
/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php
```

into

```
/app/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php
```

and making your changes to the copy. Cake will automatically use this copy you provide rather than what is in the core.

Only do this as a last resort. You'll become responsible for maintaining your own copy of the MySQL driver, and you won't receive security and performance updates to it unless you patch it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything in Cake.  Just update your MySQL table, and change the column type from 'tinyint' to 'int'.  It will store in MySQL the same way, and Cake will automatically know to return the int value, rather than the boolean (true/false).

Remember to delete your model cache files, after updating the MySQL database, in case the app is still reading from the cache.

Comment: But then he loses the automagic regarding checkboxes in forms. I don't see any point in messing with the type here.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the column length to a value greater than 1, then CakePHP will return the column as a string rather than a boolean.  TINYINT can be up to 3 characters long, so you can simply run the following query on your table while keeping the TINYINT format:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` MODIFY `your_column_name` TINYINT(3);
```

Comment: See my comment above as well.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to change the type of the column then you can [cast](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp) and get the desired value, below code can serve as alternative.

FYI: registered = tinyint(1)

```
$this->MODEL_NAME->query("SELECT id,CAST(registered AS SIGNED) as registered FROM users where id = 11223344;");
```